# Fullcalendar get data from php not update

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    redo(1);

    $("select").change(function () {
        var str = "";
        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            str = $(this).val() + " ";
        });
        console.log(str);
        redo(str);
    }); 

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    function redo(t) {
        $.getJSON("getPrenotazioni.php",{action:"date","cameraid":t}, function(data){
            $('#calendar').html("");
            console.log(data);

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable: false, 
                events: data,
                color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
                textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
            });
        });

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
    }
});
```

And the PHP code is:

```
<?php
$d = getVids($db,'ji_prenotazione','da_data,a_data','WHERE cameraid='.$_GET['cameraid']);

switch ($_GET['action'])
{
    case 'date':
        if (count($d)>0) {
            for($i=0;$i<count($d);$i++)
            {
                $str[] = array('title' => utf8_encode('xxx'),'start'=>$d[$i]['da_data']."T08:30",'end'=>$d[$i]['a_data']."T08:30");
            }
        }
        else
            $str[] = array('title' => '','start'=>'','end'=>'');

        $json = array('events'=>($str));
        break;
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

It seems to work but if I change something into the database, for example, if I delete all entries and refresh the webpage, the previous values are still there in the calendar.

What am I missing?

Comment: Which browser are you using to test your PHP+Javscript (AJaX) implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I asked what browser you are using is because all browsers behave different when executing AJaX requests. Basically a browser listens to several 'headers' inside a request response. One of these 'headers' sets the expiration date for the data downloaded, which you don't set (assuming this is the complete code). If you keep requesting data over the same URL, you will get the 'cached' result instead of the new result.

Forcing the browser to request new data every time can be done through PHP, using the `header()` function. *Note* that this function **has** to be called **before any output is sent to the browser**. The headers you have to include are like this:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

The first header will (obviously) tell the browser to revalidate the content on every request, the second will invalidate the cache immediately (which is used in older browsers).

Another option to do this, using Javascript instead of PHP, is to alter the URL on every request. This is not the best option, since it will create new cache data on every reload of the page, but it will work. You can do this by adding some random URL data (like `"getPrenotazioni.php?id=" + Math.random()`).

**Note that** I am far from sure that this is your problem, but it is likely considering your code you provided. You can simply check this by opening the page in IE (or any other browser that you had already open) after you made a change and see if the pages differ amongst browsers. Alternatively you can load the page after you made change and if nothing changed, clear your cache and reload (`CTRL + F5`).

Comment: Thanks man!I continously sure that Internet is like an infinite manual: you put the answer and some person, kindly and genious and more expert than you, will appear soon! It worked like a charm!

Comment: Wait a minute. On my local WebServer+Chrome, it works. But if I upload all to an hosted service, same problem as before.

Comment: Ok, then the search continues :) *Question:* If you try the same page in a different browser (on the hosted service), will it load different data? (When you clear the cache for example.)

Comment: I have to say that I am using the script inside word press. If I delete all cookies in the browser, my script works. Otherwise, not.

Comment: Did you try the 'random URL'-tick? Still sounds like there is a caching issue, using a random URL should circumvent it - as I said it's not the best solution but better than nothing.

Comment: Then it is indeed a caching problem, like I described. I'm not sure where you load your PHP code, but if it is a plugin for Wordpress you have to be sure that the wordpress caching is either turned off for that page or use the random URL trick. (By default caching is on in Wordpress, meaning that it will send a different header() before you sent yours.)

Comment: I used my script inside an iframe which I inserted in a WP page. Your trick works ( I mean that of random number).

Comment: Well, inside an `iframe` it should work with the `header()` command, or let me rephrase that: Wordpress shouldn't interfere with the `header()` commands. That said, a webserver has many more tricks up its sleeve - like Apache can also alter the page header. Shared hosting providers sometimes do this to limit the number of requests to their sever. If the JSON-data is not that large, I would use the URL trick as it is far less hassle (and already works).